# I'm trying to find a nice way to read a log file in real time using python

Tags: python, file, file-io, io

I would like to stop reading when i find a specific string in that file .How can i do it.

```
os.chdir('/root/.jenkins/jobs/pip2/builds/47')
fo = open('log','w+')
```

Comment: Is the log file being written to as you're reading it?

Comment: yes it is @Scovetta

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file and use `for` loop to read it line by line:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        #read this line
        if 'special string' in line:
            break
```

The above code only reads one line at a time. When the next line is read, the previous line will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [`takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) function to read all lines up to the point it matches your specific string as follows:

```
import itertools

specific_string = 'line 5'

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for line in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x.strip() != specific_string, f_input):
        print line,
```

So if `input.txt` contained:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
```

You would get the following output:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

---

Or for the opposite effect, to see all lines after your specific string you can use [`dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) as follows:

```
import itertools

specific_string = 'line 5'

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for line in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x.strip() != specific_string, f_input):
        print line,
```

Giving you:

```
line 5
line 6
line 7
```